# Vuelidate TypeError with axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuelidate

I'm doing a duplicate test on a user with vuelidate and I'm receiving a TypeError on a `errors[0].$message` which is in a p tag that is getting rendered only when there is an error

Here's the code

```html
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-row>
            <v-col cols="12">
                <label>Username</label>
            </v-col>
            <v-col cols="12">
                <input type="text" v-model.lazy="username" placeholder="Username" @blur="v$.username.$touch">
                <p v-if="v$.username.$error" class="red--text">{{v$.username.$errors[0].$message}}</p>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import useVulidate from '@vuelidate/core'
import {required, helpers, minLength} from '@vuelidate/validators'

const isUsernameTaken = (value) => axios.get('userunique', {params: {username: value}}).then(res => {return res.data})

export default{
    setup(){
        return {
            v$: useVulidate()
        }
    },

    data(){
        return {
            username: ''
        }
    },
    validations(){
        return{
            username: {
                required,
                minLength: minLength(4),
                isUserUnique: helpers.withMessage('Username taken', helpers.withAsync(isUsernameTaken))
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And the Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$message')

vue.runtime.esm.js:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$message')"
```

Validation works fine but error in console is kind of buugging me any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in Vuelidate's logic. The [docs for `$error`](https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/api/state.html#error) state...

> Equivalent to this.$dirty && !this.$pending && this.$invalid.

However in testing it doesn't appear to honour the `$pending` state.

This means that while your async validator is running, `$error` can be `true` and `$errors` can be empty.

A simple work-around for this is to use a different condition for rendering the error block...

```html
<p v-if="v$.username.$errors.length" class="red--text">
  {{ v$.username.$errors[0].$message }}
</p>
```

---

Issue raised with Vuelidate here ~ https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/issues/1046